# Awk substitute command issue

Tags: unix, shell

I am trying to open a log file and manipulate lines if required.  For example

> 2010-01-31 00:05:59,400 -0500 | [VHX4077ff8Ze1sTnE-op51V] |
>   [TB-bce11b:-16a2-5ed9f542] | [6C7CA345F63F835CB353FF15BD6C5E052EXX8E7A
>   | 1000107@Superfly | 31933782 | 172.9.8.3 | DEVICE_ID_CREATED]

I need to edit column 5 and remove everything before the *Superfly*. Essentially remove whatever number is there and the '@' symbol.  This file will have entries where column 5 does not have the number@ entry and that line will not need to be edited.  And the number could be any number of digits before the @.  I have tried to use awk's substitute command but I cannot get it to work.

My script:

```
awk -F "|" {' sub(".*@","",$5) print $5 '} test.log
```

> awk: cmd. line:3: print $5
>   awk: cmd. line:3: ^ syntax error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk -F "|" {' sub(".*@","",$5); print $5 '} test.log
```

Missing semicolon after the first statement.

Comment: Thanks MechS, I am still getting an error after trying your command:

awk:  sub(".*@","",$5); print $5 
awk:                    ^ syntax error

Comment: awk -F "|" {' sub(".*@","",$5); print $5 '} test.log


from my linux command line with your sample data yields "SuperFly"


Your awk interpreter may be requiring a ; after the last statement too

awk -F "|" {' sub(".*@","",$5); print $5; '} test.log


Mine did not.

Comment: As an FYI, I generally find it easier to use the -f parameter and edit a file.  It's more readable down the road and a lot of editors might have noted the bad syntax.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what is happening with my setup. I am running Suse Linux 10.  Is there another way to do this via a script?  I will need this to run everyday on multiple large files and change this column.  

Script now:
awk -F "|" {' sub(".*@","",$5); print $5; '} test.log

Same error:
awk:  sub(".*@","",$5); print $5; 
awk:                    ^ syntax error

Comment: I have also tried the same script and data on a CentOS 5 system.  And I get the same error.

Comment: Working fine on my ubuntu.  Try putting the code  {sub(".*@","",$5); print $5;} in a file and running awk with the -f parameter to the .awk file with this code in it.  The only other thing I can think of is the single quotes '.  I'm not sure why you have those on the inside of the {} braces.  Awk treats each set of braces as a rule against input.

Comment: awk -F "|" '{ sub(".*@","",$5); print $5; }' test.log worked fine on CentOS.  It was your quotes throwing you off along with other syntax errors.

Comment: Yep, you got it Mech. I just ran it with moving the single quotes outside the {} and it worked like a charm.  Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

are you editing the whole file and replacing every line with the value of column 5? if not,

```
awk -F"|" '$5~/@/{ sub(".*@","",$5) }{print}' OFS="|" file
```